# how to append dictionary with dictinoary included list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my dictionary

```
final_dic=dict()
final_dic['ID']=""
```

so the dictionary is final_dic={'ID':''}

I want to append dictionary which is included list into final_dic value but when I tried that I got the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

so how can i append that?

this is my dictionary

```
{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}
```

so I expect the result

`final_dic={'ID':'{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}'}`

Comment: as per your expectation you need it as a string. so try, final_dic['id']='{}'.format({40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']})

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any value to a key in a dictionary like this.

```
d = dict()
d['Key'] = [1, 2, 3]
```

List can be list of dictionary like this

```
d['Key'] = [{'ID': 1}, {'ID': 2}, {'ID': 3}]
```

If you want to assign a dictionary to a key like this

```
d['Key'] = {'KEY': [{'ID': 1}, {'ID': 2}, {'ID': 3}]}
```

In your expected result that you have mentioned i.e.

> final_dic={'ID':'{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}'}

`'{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}'` is a dictionary which is converted to string. You can convert dictionary to string like this

```
import json
dict_to_json = json.dumps(any dictionay)
```

Comment: but if the key is two dictionary?
i know that if that situation the last is only alive

Comment: ex) final_dic={'ID':'{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}','ID':'{30: ['{CODE:1675, RANK:11}', '{CODE:9124, RANK:22}']}}

Comment: i wish if the dictionary keys two i want to get the all of them above the example

Comment: The key in expected result that you have mentioned is not a dictionary. It is value which is dictionary.

Comment: ohh.. really.. so is there any way to make like that?

Comment: You can convert your dictionary to string using `json.dumps`. See the updated answer

Comment: ok thankyou also final_dic={'ID':'{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}'} this is my original result but i want to make
final_dic={'ID':'40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']'}

so how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it step by step:

```
final_dic = dict()
final_dic['ID'] = ''
tmp_ls = ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']
tmp_dic[40] = tmp_ls
final_dic['ID'] = tmp_dic
```

And you'll get the following result:

```
>>> final_dic
{'ID': {40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}}
```

Comment: thank you for answering but i want to get result { "ID": '{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}']}', "ID": '{42: ['{CODE:1675, RANK:11}']}' }

Comment: You can't. 'ID' is a key in a dictionary and the key should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

as per your expectation you need it as a string. so try, `final_dic['ID']='{}'.format({40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']})`

```
print(final_dic)
```

you will get,

```
{
 "ID": '{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}'
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering but i want to get result 
{
 "ID": '{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}']}',
 "ID": '{42: ['{CODE:1675, RANK:11}']}'
}

Comment: so is there any way to get the result which above

Answer (score 0):

You can update the dictionary like this :

```
final_dic = dict()
final_dic['ID'] = ''
tmp_dict = {40 : ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}
final_dic.update({'ID' : tmp_dict})
```

Then you will get the output:

```
>>> final_dic
{'ID': {40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}', '{CODE:924, RANK:2}']}}
```

Comment: thank you for answering but i want to get result { "ID": '{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}']}', "ID": '{42: ['{CODE:1675, RANK:11}']}' }

Comment: @hognkun FIrst of all the key should be unique in a dictionary. In your expected result they key "ID" is coming twice. That's something violates the dictionary concept.

Comment: yes... i know already know that so is there any way similar format to make it

Comment: output = ""
lst = ["{40: ['{CODE:675, RANK:1}']}", "{42: ['{CODE:1675, RANK:11}"]

for item in lst:
       output += '"ID" : \'{}\','.format(item)
       
output = "{" + output[:-1] + "}"
@hognkun

Try this but the output will be in a string format, we can't make a dictionary in this format since it contradicts the dict concept.